# Security of Reusing a One-Time Pad with Complement Messages with Errors

Tags: one-time-pad, semantic-security

Let's say I have two binary messages ($m_0$ and $m_1$) of length $n$ which are bitwise complements of each other such that $$m_0 \xleftarrow{r} \{0,1\}^n \text{  and  } m_1 = \overline{m_0}$$

If I perform a one-time pad encryption of $m_0$ and $m_1$ with the same key, I would only leak that the messages are bitwise complements of each other (but not the contents of the $m_0$ or $m_1$).

Now my question is if $m_1$ has a bit-flip error. For example, there is an integer $0 < i < n$ where $m_1[i] = m_0[i]$

Does this error leak the key at index $i$? Does this error leak either message at index $i$?

My intuition says no because we are performing a one-time pad of the same message at index $i$ but I may be missing something...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your intuition is correct.

This error leaks only information, that m1[i] = m0[i]. There is still 50% chance for that particular key bit to be 0 or 1 and attacker still cannot distinguish between those two.